# Using JSF, JPA and DAO. Without Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jpa, dao

till now i still worked with JSF and JPA without DAOs. Now i'd like to use DAOs. But how can i initialize the EntityManager in the DAO-Classes?

```
public class AdresseHome {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void persist(Adresse transientInstance) {
        log.debug("persisting Adresse instance");
        try {
            entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
}
```

Have I to use Spring or is there a solution that works without Spring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your container doesn't inject the EntityManager for you, you can get one with:

```
EntityManagerFactory factory;
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpatest");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Where "jpatest" from the unit defined in your persistence.xml

Comment: So I Still need to create an EntityManager for each DAO?

Answer (score 5):

Java EE 5 doesn't support injection in non managed component so without Spring you'll have to use **an application-managed entity manager** here (and consequently to manage its lifecycle at the application level).

Actually, Java EE 5+ doesn't really advocates using the DAO pattern ([Has JPA Killed the DAO?](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/09/jpa-dao) is a nice article on this topic) and wrapping the entity manager which implements the [Domain Store](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/DomainStore.htm) pattern, which does pretty much of what DAO does, in a DAO doesn't really make sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for you is to implement your DAO itself as a SLSB. That way you can inject the EntityManger rather than creating it. But it has it's own bad effects like too many session beans. chaining of the beans etc which is a sort of bad parctice.