# How to connect to external MySQL server from Glassfish

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL server. I have succesfully made a connection from Eclipse (DataSource view) and can now browse the content of the database.

But now I want to be able to use that database in my Java EE 6 application and it does not work. What I have tried:

Added the username, password, servername, URL, Port as properties in the administration panel.

This is the URL I use: jdbc:mysql://MYHOST:3306/MYDATABASE probably nothing wrong with it. I have also added the my IP to the remote list in CPanel so I am allowed to connect remotely. I have downloaded this driver: http://www.java.net/external?url=http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and added it to the domains/domain1/lib folder.

I also see 4 other folders there; databases, ext, applibs and classes so I added the driver to in those folders to just to be sure. Is this wrong? Do I need to add the driver to some folder in my Eclipse project in order to get it to work?

Resource Type: javax.sql.DataSource
Datasource classname: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource

**UPDATE**

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method]
>   @PostConstruct public
>   no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.QuestionController.intialize() on
>   no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.QuestionController@10614f3d
>
> root cause
>
> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke
>   [method] @PostConstruct public
>   no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.QuestionController.intialize() on
>   no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.QuestionController@10614f3d
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> root cause
>
> javax.ejb.EJBException
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.
>   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1

EJB:

```
    @Override
    public List<Question> all() {

//      List<Question> list = new ArrayList<Question>();
//      Question question = new Question();
//      question.setDescription("SDfasfasdfasf");
//      question.setId(32);
//      question.setImage("sdafasdf");
//      list.add(question);
//      
//      return list;
//      
        return questionDao.all();

    }
```

JSF bean

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class QuestionController {

    @EJB
    private QuestionLocalBusiness questionManager;

    private List<Question> questions;

    @PostConstruct
    public void intialize() {
        questions = questionManager.all();      
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> list) {
        questions = list;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049 Unable to invoke [method] @PostConstruct public com.bpoint.interfaces.QuestionController.intialize() on com.bpoint.interfaces.QuestionController@10614f3d
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:595)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.postConstruct(ManagedBean.java:200)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:340)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:87)
    at no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.org$jboss$weld$bean-SertifikatWeb_war-ManagedBean-class_no$breakpoint$sertifikat$interfaces$QuestionController_$$_WeldClientProxy.getQuestions(org$jboss$weld$bean-SertifikatWeb_war-ManagedBean-class_no$breakpoint$sertifikat$interfaces$QuestionController_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:55)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:456)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:201)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:180)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:85)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:305)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:299)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invoke(WeldMethodImpl.java:193)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.defaultPostConstruct(AbstractClassBean.java:591)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:5193)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5091)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy231.all(Unknown Source)
    at no.breakpoint.sertifikat.interfaces.QuestionController.intialize(QuestionController.java:24)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at no.breakpoint.sertifikat.application.QuestionManagerEJB.all(QuestionManagerEJB.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 79 more
```

DAO:

```
package no.breakpoint.sertifikat.infrastructure;

import java.util.List;

@NamedQuery(name = "allQuestions", query = "SELECT q FROM Question q")
public class DefaultQuestionDao implements QuestionDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyDatabasePU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void create(Question question) {
        entityManager.persist(question);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Question question) {
        entityManager.remove(question);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Question question) {
        entityManager.merge(question);
    }

    @Override
    public Question read(Integer id) {
        return entityManager.find(Question.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Question> all() {
        TypedQuery<Question> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("allQuestions", Question.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

If I uncomment what I have commented now the dataTable I use works and the 500 error goes away. But when I try to get it from the database it gives me that.

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried to ping the db from the admin console (http://localhost:4848)? Regarding the parameters you are passing, maybe you can try removing servername and port (they are already given in the URL)

Comment: @perissf The ping is succesful. I added more to my question.

Comment: When the bean method is invoked, the variable questionManager seems to be null

Comment: But all works if I uncomment what I have commented now in the EJB and vica versa

Comment: Ok, so the NPE is probably thrown on the invokation of questionDao.all() method. You have the class names and line numbers, we don't. The stack trace should give you hints on where to look in debugging, otherwise you should post the questionDao as well

Comment: Added it the dao source code at the bottom

Comment: mmm... it seems that the exception is thrown somewhere else: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at no.breakpoint.sertifikat.application.QuestionManagerEJB.all(QuestionManagerEJB.java:52)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4332/discussion-between-bpdeveloper-and-perissf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at no.breakpoint.sertifikat.application.QuestionManagerEJB.all(QuestionManagerEJB.java:52)

So, the [`EntityManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) is `null`? The [`@PersistenceContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) will only be injected in container/framework managed classes such as a [`@Stateless`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) EJB, a CDI [`@Named`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Named.html) bean, a JSF [`@ManagedBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) bean, etc. Your `DefaultQuestionDao` however doesn't seem to be managed at all.

Given the setup so far, I'd start marking your `DefaultQuestionDao` as a [`@Stateless`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html) EJB. The whole setup is by the way confusing at best, the stacktrace tells about `QuestionManagerEJB` which I don't see back in the code snippets, only a `DefaultQuestionDao` and a `QuestionBusinessLocal`. Perhaps you need to inject the `DefaultQuestionDao` as `@EJB` in your `QuestionManagerEJB` as well.

Further, there's another problem: that [`@NamedQuery`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html) has got to be annotated on an [`@Entity`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) class or one of its superclasses, or it won't be found.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to make the DAO an stateless EJB in order to inject persistencecontext?

Comment: Yes. You can also just get rid of that extra DAO layer. Java EE 6 has almost killed it. ORM became a standardized part of Java EE API since the new JPA API. All DB actions are now basically oneliners and you can switch JPA implementations (e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink, etc). Why would you create an extra abstract layer? Would you ever switch to plain vanilla JDBC or old Hibernate or any other 3rd party ORM framework? If not, what's the value of DAO then? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818589/java-ee-architecture-are-daos-still-recommended-when-using-an-orm-like-jpa-2

Comment: Could you come on the chat started in the comment on my original question and I post some more code? And yes I find it rather un-useful but every where I see they use DAO's

Comment: Awesome! I removed the DAO and it works! However, if you have time could you please come on the chat because I have some quick questions related to it? :)

Comment: You're welcome. I don't want to overcome harsh, nothing related to you in person, but I'm in general not interested in participating in chat. Just post a clear and concrete question or hire a consultant.

Comment: Okey then I ask here; What is the difference between (@)EJB and (@)Inject

Comment: I meant, as a new question. This is offtopic. But ala, `@EJB` is from the Java EE 5 ages and identifies an injection point of a `@Stateless` or `@Stateful` EJB instance (and since Java EE 6 also `@Singleton`). `@Inject` is new in Java EE 6 and is initially designed for `@Named` instances, but can also be used on container managed EJBs.